# Probability of All Decimal Digits Appearing in a Ten-Digit-Block of Pi Assuming Normality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, decimal-expansion, experimental-mathematics

In their book *A Biography of the World's Most Mysterious Number*, Posamentier and Lehmann mentioned that "Conway has indicated that if you separate the decimal value of $\pi$ into groups of ten places, the probability of each of the ten digits appearing in any of these blocks is about $\frac{1}{40000}$."

I wonder what exactly is the value of this probability assuming the normality of $\pi$?

Comment: Well, in a *specific* block, it'd be $\frac {10!}{10^{10}}=0.00036288\approx \frac1{2755}$.  But if you mean *any* of the infinite number of blocks it'd be $1$.  I... don't know why the author said that.  (The author most have meant something different than what was expressed.)

Comment: @fleablood The sentence put in quotation marks in my original question was exactly what they said. In the book there is also a visualization of separating the digits: $\pi = 3.1415926535 \text{ } 8979323846 \text{ } 2643383279 \ldots$. I think they meant the specific blocks of ten as indicated by their separation. I wonder if Conway himself had left any literature regarding this question?

Comment: I'm finding lots of references to that.  Most are say the probability of any *specific* block.  Maybe I'm making an error in calculating the probability as $\frac {10!}{10^{10}}$ but I'm not sure how.  Also $\frac {10!}{10^{10}}= \frac {3,628,800}{10,000,000,000}$ which is small but I seem to be off be a factor of twelve.  If anyone wants to spot me... It appears that ten distinct digits occur in the 7th block.... I find it hard to believe I am right and he was wrong/and or no-one noticed.  So I figure I must be something wrong but I really can't see what.

Comment: Maybe it was Tim Conway, not John. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Conway

Comment: @fleablood Indeed all digits occur in the 7th block, and the book did mention their appearance. After mentioning that this configuration occurs in the seventh group of ten and the probability of it occurring is about one in forty thousand, it goes on saying that "every other grouping of ten has at least one repeating digit." I suppose by "every other" they meant loosely that such configuration happens rare?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, the authors explicitly mentioned J. H. Conway, I omitted his full name when I was referring to him.

Comment: I think your particular text is being a bit sloppy and naive.  It's not the probability of "any" but of any *specific* one, and obviously it's not the case the "every other grouping" has at least one repeating. It's that *most* (apparently 39,999 out of 40,000) do.  I found other sources that quote it a bit more accurately.  But they all say 40,000 whereas my calculations put it at 2,755. I have no idea why he thought 40,000 but he was no slouch so I'm questioning my calcs.... I'm pretty sure @GerryMyerson was joking. Tim Conway was a famous comedian on the Carol Burnett show.